# Definition of Lie algebra for self-defined group of matrices

Tags: matrices, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am junior in this field. I know the definition of a **Lie algebra** of a matrix group:

> The Lie algebra of a matrix group $G\subset GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the tangent space to $G$ at $I$ (identity element). It is denoted by $T_IG$.

From this definition, we know that matrices in $G$ must be invertible. So **if $G$ is not in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, then we cannot define its Lie algebra**. (The operation of this group should be multiplication.)

---

My question is:

If today I can define a new group with a new group operation. And by this
operation, I can define inverse elements. So matrices in this new group are invertible under this new operation. Can I define its tangent space and  Lie algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by "matrices in this new group" ?  Are you referring to the group elements or a matrix where the entries are in this group?

Comment: @mathematician I mean the group I defined in the particular research. 2. For example let this group be $G$.  if $A\in G$, I can always find $\operatorname{inv}(A)\in G$ with "$A\operatorname{inv} (A) = E$", where $E$ is the identity element  and $\operatorname{inv}(A)$ is the inverse element I defined in this particular group.

Comment: To add some context to the answer below: A tangent space is only defined for a continuous manifold.  So your group must have a compatible manifold structure.  It turns out continuous Lie groups are the same as smooth Lie groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your group is a smooth manifold and multiplication and inversion are smooth maps. This is the definition of a [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group). All Lie groups have a Lie algebra, but if your group is not a subgroup of $GL(n,\Bbb R)$, the Lie backet might be different from the standard one on $M(n,\Bbb R)$.